# How do I open a file with the flags provided as an i32 matching the C open function?

Tags: rust, libc

I need to open a file and I have a `&Path` and an `i32` for the flags. I can open files with `File::open(path)`, but this won't let me set the options. The documentation says I should use `OpenOptions`, but I do not see any way to get an `OpenOptions` from my `i32`. The content of my flags is defined as in `open(2)`.

The flags I am using is `526338`, if you want to test it yourself.

Comment: Where did you get the `i32`? Could it have OS-specific flags in it, or just portable `open(3p)` ones, for example?

Comment: @Ry- I got it from some weird library wrapper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are on a Unix-like system, you can use [`OpenOptionsExt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/unix/fs/trait.OpenOptionsExt.html) to set your flags:

```
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::os::unix::fs::OpenOptionsExt;

let file = OpenOptions::new()
    .read(true)
    .custom_flags(flags)
    .open(&path)?;
```

Note that you must set the access mode flags separately (e.g. by calling `read` or `write`), so if you need them you will have to handle them yourself. For example:

```
use std::os::unix::fs::OpenOptionsExt;

use libc::{O_RDONLY, O_RDWR, O_WRONLY};

let file = OpenOptions::new()
    .custom_flags(flags)
    .read((flags & O_ACCMODE == O_RDONLY) || (flags & O_ACCMODE == O_RDWR))
    .write((flags & O_ACCMODE == O_WRONLY) || (flags & O_ACCMODE == O_RDWR))
    .open(&path)?;
```

Comment: When I do this, I get `Os { code: 22, kind: InvalidInput, message: "Invalid argument" }`. I know the flags are correct since when I call `libc::open` with the same arguments it works

Comment: Sorry `mode` is for the access mode, the flags for `open(2)` are set with `custom_flags`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: The flags I use is `526338`, if you want to test it yourself. I already tried `custom_flags`, but it didn't help. I also tried both (because the documentation says some things are masked and others aren't), but still the same error.

Comment: You need to call either `read` or `write` to set the access mode (tested here: if I don't call either, I get the "Invalid argument" error even without `custom_flags`. If I call `.read (true)` then it works with `.custom_flags (526338)`).

Comment: I think you can also use ".mode(mode.bits())" for read/write

Answer (score 0):

To give an example of the answer above, something like this works for me:

```rust
use std::os::unix::fs::OpenOptionsExt;
// Also uses "nix" crate for flags, but many are available in "libc"
// or you can use manual values

pub fn open_file(
    file_path: PathBuf,
    flags: nix::fcntl::OFlag,
    mode: nix::sys::stat::Mode,
) -> Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error> {
    std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .read(
            (flags.contains(nix::fcntl::OFlag::O_RDONLY)
                || flags.contains(nix::fcntl::OFlag::O_RDWR)),
        )
        .write(
            (flags.contains(nix::fcntl::OFlag::O_WRONLY)
                || flags.contains(nix::fcntl::OFlag::O_RDWR)),
        )
        .custom_flags(flags.bits())
        .mode(mode.bits())
        .open(file_path)
}

#[test]
fn test_open_file() {
    let file_path = PathBuf::from("test_open_file.txt");
    let file = open_file(
        file_path,
        nix::fcntl::OFlag::O_RDWR | nix::fcntl::OFlag::O_CREAT,
        nix::sys::stat::Mode::S_IRWXU,
    )
    .unwrap();
    assert!(file.metadata().unwrap().is_file());
}
```